# In the same query INSERT, can two VALUES being NOW() return a different time?

Tags: mysql, query, datetime, mariadb-10.2

I met a query similar to

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, Created, Updated) VALUES (null, NOW(), NOW())
```

having column definitions

```
| Created   | datetime |
| Updated   | datetime |
```

Will in this case MySQL set the NOW() value to the current time and return that same values to both calls, or will that query run the (improbable) risk of having two slightly different times for Created and Updated?

*Note*: I can't change the field types.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The time returned by `NOW()`, and other date time functions, is derived from the [start time](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/mariadb-10.2.29/sql/sql_class.h#L2344) of the query. The `THD` class here is used to contain all the information for the connection. The `NOW()` function [implementation](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/mariadb-10.2.29/sql/item_timefunc.cc#L1720) grabs this value and returns it into the `now_time` structure.

MySQL [docs for `NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) also state:

> NOW() returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the statement began to execute. ...

You will always get the same `NOW()` value from anywhere in the query.

```
MariaDB [test]> select now(),sleep(10),now();
+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| now()               | sleep(10) | now()               |
+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 2021-03-22 14:17:05 |         0 | 2021-03-22 14:17:05 |
+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Worth noting, that this isn't per transaction:

```
MariaDB [test]> start transaction
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]>  select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2021-03-22 14:20:53 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select sleep(2);
+----------+
| sleep(2) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (2.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2021-03-22 14:21:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is the answer I was expecting, thanks. My tests (see below) empirically tend to that same conclusion (but your idea of adding *sleep()* in between is simpler, and more conclusive).

Comment: or you could go trickier structures like `select now(),sleep(2), (select sleep(2) + now()) union all select now(), sleep(2), now();` same result however.

Comment: If you have binary logging turned on, you can see the timestamp of each command logged along the command. This timestamp is used for `NOW()`.

Answer (score 17):

Another aspect:  `SYSDATE()` can be different, but `NOW()` cannot.

```
mysql> select now(6), sysdate(6), now(6), sysdate(6);
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| now(6)                     | sysdate(6)                 | now(6)                     | sysdate(6)                 |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| 2021-03-21 22:02:28.983211 | 2021-03-21 22:02:28.983368 | 2021-03-21 22:02:28.983211 | 2021-03-21 22:02:28.983370 |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm using `(6)` so we can see the time down to the microsecond.  Note how the `NOW` calls are identical and the smallest values.  Meanwhile, the `SYSDATE` calls are later and not the same as each other.

----- 2006-03-31 5.0.20 & not yet released 5.1.8 -- Functionality Added or Changed -- -----

Added the [--sysdate-is-now](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_sysdate-is-now) option to mysqld to enable [SYSDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate) to be treated as an alias for [NOW()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now). See [Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html). (Bug #15101)

----- 2005-09-22 5.0.13 Release Candidate -- Bugs Fixed -- -----

The [SYSDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate) function now returns the time at which it was invoked. In particular, within a stored routine or trigger, [SYSDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate) returns the time at which it executes, not the time at which the stored routine or triggering statement began to execute. (Bug #12480)

Comment: Nice addition .

Comment: One obscure practical use:  To measure replication delay.  The `NOW()` value is passed through replication, not replicated.  `SYSDATE()` is recomputed on the Replica.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't find the answer from @nbk satisfying enough for my needs (especially "No, as long as you have no micro seconds in your datetime and a really very slow server, it could be possible").

So I simulated a kind of very slow server.

My Linux desktop MB has 6 cores, I made this C program

```
#define COUNT 10000000000L

double busy() {
     volatile double z = rand() / M_PI;

     for(long l=0 ; l<COUNT ; l++) {
          z += sqrt(M_PI);
     }
     return z;
}
```

and in the main

```
 int n = atoi(*++argv); // input 10 

 while(n--) {
      if ( ! fork()) {
            printf("%d => %lf\n", n, busy());
            exit(0);
      }
 }

 pid_t wpid;
 int status = 0;
 while ((wpid = wait(&status)) > 0);
```

That makes *n* threads very busy. With *n* = 10, the desktop was *really* busy...

While that was running (as *root*, to ensure the system doesn't try to salvage some resources for itself :) I had prepared this earlier

```
create table a (num int auto_increment primary key,
   d1 datetime(6), d2 datetime(6), d3 datetime(6), d4 datetime(6));
```

and a file made of 1000 lines

```
insert into a values(null,now(6),now(6),now(6),now(6));
```

So when the PC was running 10 threads *busy()* on 6 cores [all were at 100%], I injected the 1000 inserts into the table, took a bit longer than usual, then

```
select * from a where d1 <> d2 or d1 <> d3 or d1 <> d4;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Yes! MySQL is really well made! (seriously, I'm always amazed at the quality in algorithms and system programming behind this DBMS).

Comment: Isn't MySQL open source? Why not just check the code base? There's probably a unit test in there somewhere, for this.

Comment: Well, it took me less than 5 minutes to write this. Downloading the huge code from MySQL and looking in the huge code base would likely take more than that...

Comment: Except that it suffers from the "works for me" syndrome, without actually understanding how it is designed and implemented. The problem with black-box testing, is you're discovering probable outcomes.  @danblack's answer, has a reference to the code.

Comment: @jwdonahue I don't know from what *you* suffer :) but as said, the only answer at the time was not what I was expecting, so I covered the case they mentioned, "very slow server", and had a lot of fun doing my own tests (then with 20k lines and 20 threads, very low probability of a less than a microsecond difference). It was indeed empirical, until a more conclusive answer was posted, danblack, that I duly commented and accepted.

Comment: I think I suffer from 30 years of development work, and nearly half of that in test. I've seen tests like this run for days, turning up false results, and then fail when compiled or run on a different machine, or against a different database instance. Worse yet, is when you do drill into the code and find it's written to do as you expect, and then two months later, that's not how it works anymore.

Comment: So you get in the habit of looking for documentation that might indicate an intent to preserve that behavior (standards & specifications), and you develop defensive coding habits that avoid taking such dependencies wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

No, the will be no difference

as MysQL Writes in the manual

> NOW() returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the statement began to execute.

This seems to be a diffrent behaviour as all other functions, which are run column by column.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Created DATETIME , Updated DATETIME)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mytable (id, Created, Updated) VALUES (null, NOW(), NOW())
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mytable (id, Created, Updated) VALUES (null, NOW(3), NOW(3))
> ```

> ```
> SELECT MICROSECOND(Created),MICROSECOND(Updated) FROM mytable
> ```
>
> ```
> MICROSECOND(Created) | MICROSECOND(Updated)
> -------------------: | -------------------:
>                    0 |                    0
>                    0 |                    0
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable2 (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Created DATETIME(3) , Updated DATETIME(3))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mytable2 (id, Created, Updated) VALUES (null, NOW(3), NOW(3))
> ```

> ```
> SELECT MICROSECOND(Created),MICROSECOND(Updated) FROM mytable2
> ```
>
> ```
> MICROSECOND(Created) | MICROSECOND(Updated)
> -------------------: | -------------------:
>               186000 |               186000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d97c1958f4f33538587a596daee91723)*

Comment: The answer is not clear. Is it possible or not for NOW() to return different results in the same query?

Comment: MySQL docs state that ***NOW() returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the statement began to execute.*** so I don't see how you have two different values from the same query.